# Database error when accessing $_SERVER variable in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter and I'm trying to echo `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. But whenever I tried to access `$_SERVER` variable I'm getting database error.

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to select the specified database: MY_DB_NAME

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

Is it a Codeigniter restriction or a bug.

Comment: You have wrong configuration in application/config/databese.php I think.

Comment: @jakon No, everything is working fine if I don't touch $_SERVER variable.

Comment: @Balakrishnan Where are you echoing $_SERVER variable? In your controller or where?

Comment: @RahilWazir from a Controller.

Comment: @Balakrishnan This seems odd. Works fine here. Can you edit your question whats the prior step to `$_SERVER` or post your controller code.

Comment: I hosted my app on Hostinger and Just yesterday only I configured it to use PHP 5.5 from PHP 5.3. But, in PHP info it shows PHP 5.3.28.

Comment: And also base model named my_model.php was not loaded until I rename it to MY_Model.php.

Comment: I don't know why I'm having unstability with codeigniter. my_model.php was working fine in my previous project which uses the same version of Codeigniter 2.1.4.

Comment: `my_model` and `MY_Model` will differ in linux environments.

Answer (score 1):

So, you can use :

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
echo $this->agent->referrer();
```

Read also:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html

Comment: +1 But, this doesn't answer me why I'm getting database error.

Comment: Which version of CI are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Codeigniter 2.1.4 and PHP 5

Comment: Which version of PHP5 ? It makes largggge difference :)

Comment: Its PHP version 5.3.28